# How can add a text append text to richTextBox only if the text is different from the one already exist?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this method i'm calling every X minutes using a timer.

```
public void Scroll()
        {
            listsext.Ext(page);
            combindedString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ListsExtractions.myList);
            richTextBox1.SelectAll();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(combindedString);
            richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;            
            richTextBox1.AppendText(combindedString);
        }
```

The problem is that now it will keep adding to the richTextBox the content in combindedString over and over again.
I need somehow to check each time if the content in combindedString already exist in the richTextBox if not meaning it's new content then AppendText it.

If it's the same already exist do nothing don't add it.

EDIT

I write to a text file the content of the ombindedString variable .The first content the lines is the combindedString:

```
המשטרה עצרה אמא ל2 ילדים קטנים שבעלה נעצר בחשד למעורבות בעלה בכריתת עצים
15:03 דווח במקור בתאריך : 09.03.15 : שעה
http://rotter.net/forum/scoops1/189935.shtml

אדם החשוד בעבירת מין בקטינים נעצר לאחר שהתלונן על 2 שסוחטים אותו על רקע מעשיו
14:50 דווח במקור בתאריך : 09.03.15 : שעה
http://rotter.net/forum/scoops1/189932.shtml

אינדונזיה: 5 הרוגים בקריסת האנגר בנמל תעופה
14:44 דווח במקור בתאריך : 09.03.15 : שעה
http://rotter.net/forum/scoops1/189930.shtml

אום אל-פחם: מספר חשודים עוכבו בחשד למעורבות במימון טרור
14:04 דווח במקור בתאריך : 09.03.15 : שעה
http://rotter.net/forum/scoops1/189914.shtml

אלמנתו של רפ''ק ג'דעאן אסעד, שנרצח בפיגוע הדריסה, ילדה בן
13:05 דווח במקור בתאריך : 09.03.15 : שעה
http://rotter.net/forum/scoops1/189884.shtml

תנאי ליברמן לכניסה לממשלה עונש מוות למחבלים חובת חתימה על מסמך נאמנות
12:39 דווח במקור בתאריך : 09.03.15 : שעה
http://rotter.net/forum/scoops1/189868.shtml

תלמיד תיכון מרחובות חשוד שהפעיל מעבדה ביתית לזיוף תעודות זהות ואישורי מחלה
12:03 דווח במקור בתאריך : 09.03.15 : שעה
http://rotter.net/forum/scoops1/189856.shtml

הצביעות של רענן שקד: האשים את אמהות 3 החטופים ומגנה את חגי הוברמן
11:43 דווח במקור בתאריך : 09.03.15 : שעה
http://rotter.net/forum/scoops1/189848.shtml
```

And this is a screenshot i couldnt copy the text of the richTextBox1.Text

[richTextBox1.Text content image](http://postimg.org/image/d61j6fghd/)

co uld be that the format of the text in the combindedString and the richTextBox1.Text looks different so it think it's not exist ?

Update:

Not sure if it's important but the combindedString i'm adding the text to it from the variable ListExtractions.myList

myList is List and i build this List like that:

```
private void ListToStringList(List<string> myl)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < AllNews.Count; i++)
            {
                myl.Add(AllNews[i].text);
                IFormatProvider provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                DateTime myTime = DateTime.ParseExact(AllNews[i].original_time, "DyyMMddTHHmm", provider);
                string results = myTime.ToString("HH:mm דווח במקור בתאריך : dd.MM.yy : שעה");
                myl.Add(results);
                myl.Add(AllNews[i].link);
                myl.Add(Environment.NewLine);
                myListWithoutLinks.Add(AllNews[i].text);
                myListWithoutLinks.Add(results);
                myListWithoutLinks.Add(Environment.NewLine);

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < myl.Count; i++)
            {
                myl[i] = Regex.Replace(myl[i], @"\t|\n|\r", "");

            }
        }
```

And use it:

```
ListToStringList(myList);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if text in richtextbox contain combinedString. If not then append to richtextbox.

```
    if(!richTextBox.Text.Contains(combinedString))
    {
       richTextBox1.AppendText(combindedString);
    }
```

Comment: Not working tried it. For some reason it keep getting inside and keep adding the text.

Comment: any example of text in richTextBox and "combinedString" ?

Comment: Yes just edited my question with this info. I can't add images since im in low level here so i add a link for an image with a screenshot of my richTextBox1.Text content and in my question added the content of combindedString. It looks like that the format is different but the content is the same no ? And in the richTextBox1 i see it like i see it in the combindedString.

Comment: Also i forgot to mention that the lines of the text are in hebrew language.

Comment: I just updated my question one again last time i wanted to show how i'm building the text that i assign to the combindedString variable. Maybe this make the different each time ?

Answer (score 0):

Use  [String.Contains()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
if (!richTextBox1.Text.Contains(combindedString))
{
 richTextBox1.AppendText(combindedString);
}
```